# VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

```
 You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

5.0.24_Ubuntur108355

Comment: Looks like you need to install virtualbox host kernel module from your package manager. And don't forget to add your user to vboxusers group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependencies

Linux headers

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

dkms package

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Comment: installing all dependencies .
not resolving.